# rest server without pear

Tags: php, xml

We have a php web site and we are trying to implement an api. To implement this API we need to send an xml request using sing RESTFUL services.

So we need to do any rest method (without pear) to post the xml request.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Use cURL to POST any data to any API and receive response from the server (it can be XML, JSON, whatever).

To compose XML request that you need to POST, use `SimpleXML` and insert it into POSTFIELDs of your request to API.

Have a look at this answer, it is similar to yours, but with one difference.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11638765/1548719

To send a POST to URL (API) you need to add several `CURLOPT` options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // using usual POST (like form submitted application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml')); // defining content type of the request we are sending
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $previouslyComposedXMLRequest); // and finally transmitting POST parameter in form of XML
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wget http://example.com/path/to/interface
```

Or in PHP you can just use the common file-/stream-functions

```
file_get_contents('http://example.com/path/to/interface');
```